# Is there a way to open localhost inside VS Code editor interally?

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, localhost, liveserver

When I was in a bootcamp, our instructor accessed localhost inside VSCode, I just forgot how to do that, does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 22):

[simple browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL0H6.png)

Like this, no one helped figure this out.

The way to do this, is using VS Code's simple browser. CRTL+SHIFT P, type simple browser, and it will open a window, add your localhost info and Bam! Simple Browser INSIDE your Visual Studio Code..

This is really beneficial for people that have laptops! If you only have 1 screen to work with, and dont want to SHIFT-TAB or split Screens because you need to view your work.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Answer (score -2):

or either you can simply install a vs code extension ["Live server"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) used by millions to view rendered pages live side by side alongwith your code.